# Is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & A \\ B & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ similar to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & CAC^{-1} \\ C^{-1}BC & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ by some transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

Consider a matrix with two entries being some operator or matrix
$$D=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A \\
B & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I want to construct another $2\times2$ matrix $S$ such that
$$SDS^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & CAC^{-1} \\
C^{-1}BC & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $C$ is some operator or matrix.

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.
The matrices $D$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & CAC^{-1} \\
C^{-1}BC & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$ are not similar in general; they do not even have the same characteristic polynomial in general.

For a counterexample, set
$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & b
\end{array}
\right)  $
and
$B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
c & 0\\
0 & d
\end{array}
\right)  $
and
$C=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)  $.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you think it possible with any additional condition? Actually, I am thinking about the case when $A,B$ are simple functions of $x$ and $C=\exp(−\mathrm{i}a\frac{d}{dx})$ is a differential operator with constant a.

Comment: @xiaohuamao: Your $C$ looks more like a shift operator than a differential operator :) But no, I'M afraid I don't know any conditions that could help.

Comment: Yes, it's the shift operator. Thanks for your opinion. I'll wait for a little while and accept your answer if no other.